# Writing Multivariate Normal (Gaussian) distribution as Exponential Family: How to deal with trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

$$
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\nc}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{#2}}
\nc{\vx}{\vect{x}}
\nc{\vmu}{\vect{\mu}}
\nc{\vSigma}{\vect{\Sigma}}
\nc{\vtheta}{\vect{\theta}}
$$

## Context

I'm reading [Graphical Models, Exponential Families, and
Variational Inference](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf) by Martin J. Wainwright and Michael I. Jordan. I've already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26648/exponential-family-representation-of-multi-variate-gaussians) post but it's very cryptic.

## Problem

I want to write the multivariate normal distribution
$$
f(\vx) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{d}{2}}\text{det}(\vSigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\vx - \vmu)^\top \vSigma^{-1}(\vx - \vmu)\right\}
$$
as being part of the exponential family. In the book (and in many other places, see [this](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-478/16-478.pdf) paper) they say $f$ belongs to the **exponential family** if it can be written as
$$
f(\vx; \vtheta) = \exp\left\{\langle\vtheta, \phi(\vx)\rangle  - A(\vtheta)\right\}
$$
where $\vtheta$ are the natural parameters of the distribution, $\phi(\vx)$ are sufficient statistics, and $A(\vtheta)$ is the log-partition function, which simply makes sure it integrates to one.

## My Attempt

Firstly, we can write the pdf as an exponential

$$
\begin{align}
f(\vx) &= (2\pi)^{-\frac{d}{2}}\text{det}(\vSigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\vx - \vmu)^\top \vSigma^{-1}(\vx - \vmu)\right\} \\
&= \exp\left\{-\frac{d}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2}|\vSigma|-\frac{1}{2}\left[\vx^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vx - \vx^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu - \vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vx + \vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu\right]\right\} \\
&= \exp\left\{\vx^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu -\frac{1}{2}\vx^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vx -\frac{1}{2}\left[d\log2\pi + \log|\vSigma| +\vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu\right]\right\}
\end{align}
$$

Next, we can see that the following expression
$$
\vx^\top \vSigma^{-1}\vx = \sum_{k=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d x_k\Sigma_{kj}x_j
$$
is actually equivalent to this
$$
\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left[\vSigma\vx\vx^\top\right] &= 
\text{tr}\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \cdots & \Sigma_{1d} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\Sigma_{d1} & \cdots & \Sigma_{dd} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1x_d\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_dx_1 & \cdots & x_d^2
\end{pmatrix}
\right]\\
&= 
\text{tr}\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^d\Sigma_{1j}x_jx_1 & \cdots & \sum_{j=1}\Sigma_{1j}x_jx_d \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\sum_{j=1}^d \Sigma_{dj}x_jx_1 & \cdots & \sum_{j=1}^d \Sigma_{dj}x_jx_d
\end{pmatrix}
\right] = \sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{j=1}^d x_{k}\Sigma_{kj}x_j
\end{align}
$$
So that we can write the pdf as
$$
f(\vx) = \exp\left\{\langle \vx, \vSigma^{-1}\vmu\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left[\vSigma\vx\vx^\top\right] -\frac{1}{2}\left[d\log2\pi + \log|\vSigma| +\vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu\right]\right\}
$$
According to the question that I've linked to we can use the Frobenius product between two **real** matrices $A$ and $B$ 
$$
\langle A, B\rangle_F = \text{tr}(A^\top B)
$$
In our case $A = \vSigma$ and $B=\vx\vx^\top$. In addition both $\vSigma$ and $\vx\vx^\top$ are **symmetric** so we have
$$
\langle \vSigma, \vx\vx^\top\rangle_F = \text{tr}(\vSigma\vx\vx^\top)
$$
This means that we can write the pdf as
$$
f(\vx) = \exp\left\{\langle \vSigma^{-1}\vmu, \vx\rangle + \left\langle -\frac{1}{2}\vSigma, \vx\vx^\top\right\rangle_F -\frac{1}{2}\left[d\log2\pi + \log|\vSigma| +\vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu\right]\right\}
$$
We can construct the following vectors
$$
\vtheta = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\vSigma^{-1}\vmu \\
-\frac{1}{2}\vSigma
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
\phi(\vx) = \begin{pmatrix}\vx \\ \vx\vx^\top
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and when taking the inner product 
$$
\langle \vtheta, \phi(\vx)\rangle
$$
we make sure to take the dot product for the first two terms, since they're both vectors
$$
\langle \vSigma^{-1}\vmu, \vx\rangle
$$
and we take the Frobenius inner product for the second terms 
$$
\left\langle -\frac{1}{2}\vSigma, \vx\vx^\top\right\rangle_F
$$
In addition we have
$$
A(\vtheta) = A\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\vSigma^{-1}\vmu \\
-\frac{1}{2}\vSigma
\end{pmatrix} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[d\log2\pi + \log|\vSigma| +\vmu^\top\vSigma^{-1}\vmu\right]
$$

Comment: I've ended up writing a blog post with the full derivation [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.com/post/multivariate-normal-as-an-exponential-family-distribution/)